# Retrieve rows from table to str_replace

Tags: php, limit, str-replace

I'm having trouble taking data from a table and using it to replace strings in html text. I need to retrieve the last 4 rows from the table, then using str_replace, automatically create hrefs. So one column is url, one is title, one is description, etc. Then I'll create 4 separate hrefs from each row. What I have so far will work for only the last result. How do I make it work for all 4?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM LINKS ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
if(!$result = mysql_query($query)){
    // query failed, handle the error here...
    $errors[] = "A fatal error occurred and this page is non-functional at this time!";
    trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br /> Due to: " . mysql_error()); // application error
} else {
    // query worked
    if(!mysql_num_rows($result)){
        // no matching rows
        $main_content .= "No rows were found!\n";
    } else {
        // query matched at least one row, use the results from the query here...
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $title1 .= $row['title'];
        $link1 .= $row['url'];
    }
}
//string replace arrays
$placeholders = array('LINK1','LINK2', 'LINK3','LINK4');
$replacevals = array($link1, $link2, $link3, $link4);

//replace the areas of the template with the posted values
$page = str_replace($placeholders,$replacevals,$template);
```

I'd like to be able to output $title2, $link2, $title3, etc.

Comment: Where is the `str_replace()` and where is the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the str_replace. I added it to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do so would be to do something like this:

```
...
// query worked
if(!mysql_num_rows($result)){
  // no matching rows
  $main_content .= "No rows were found!\n";
} 
else {
  $urls_array = Array();
  // query matched at least one row, use the results from the query here...
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $urls_array[] = "<a href='" . $row['url'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</a>";
  }
}
```

Then you end up with an array of html links set to the `$urls_array` variable.

Comment: This works well, thanks! However, I'm a bad PHPer. I need to include the echo from the $urls_array into the HTML page that's created elsewhere in the PHP code. That's why I was trying to use str_replace. But just going $link1 = echo $urls_array[1] doesn't work.

Comment: Try reading php documentation about using a [foreach loop to iterate through the array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Blah, I figured it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc). Traditionally, a [`while`](http://php.net/while) loop.

Here's an example derived from the [PHP docs](http://php.net):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

That should get you started. Welcome to StackOverflow.